# incorrect radio value eventually shown.. can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, event-handling, radio-button, getelementbyid, jquery-events

I am using some code to display radio buttons as images:

HTML:

```
<div id="skin_1" title="Walk">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_walking" value="WALKING" /><br>
    Walk
</div>

<div id="skin_2" title="Drive">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_driving" value="DRIVING" /><br>
    Drive
</div>

<div id="skin_3" title="Bike">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_bicycle" value="BICYCLING" /><br>
    Bike
</div>

<div id="skin_4" title="Transit">
<input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_transit" value="TRANSIT" /><br>
 Transit
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" onClick="testMe();">What mode is selected?</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:radio').hide().each(function () {
        var label = $("label[for=" + '"' + this.id + '"' + "]").text();
        $('<a ' + (label != '' ? 'title=" ' + label + ' "' : '') + ' class="radio-fx ' + this.name + '" href="#"><span class="radio' + (this.checked ? ' radio-checked' : '') + '"></span></a>').insertAfter(this);
    });
    $('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
        $check = $(this).prev('input:radio');
        var unique = '.' + this.className.split(' ')[1] + ' span';
                $(unique).attr('class', 'radio');
                $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'radio-checked');
                $check.attr('checked', true);
            }).on('keydown', function (e) {
                if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 32) {
                    $(this).trigger('click');
            }
    });
});
```

Problem:

Eventually after changing the radio button and clicking "What mode is selected?" enough times the WRONG radio button value is alerted.

Question:

How can I get the correct value of the radio button every time?

Here is the fiddle: [Live Fiddle Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRqqKg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added one line to clear all the checkbox:

```
$('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
   $("input[name=travel_mode]").removeAttr("checked"); // add this line
   .....
```

Full [Fiddle](http://codepen.io/sandenay/pen/RGPPKR)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable inside the function so that it gets reset on each time.

```
function testMe() {

var selected_travel_mode = $("input[name=travel_mode]:checked").val();

alert(selected_travel_mode);

}
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Eventually it will alert the wrong value.

Comment: I had checked in codepen using the suggested fix. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to reset radio checked state when select new one.

```
    var pre;
            $('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
                if(pre!==undefined)
                  $(pre).attr('checked',false);                   
                pre = $(this).prev('input:radio');
                $check = $(this).prev('input:radio');
                var unique = '.' + this.className.split(' ')[1] + ' span';
                $(unique).attr('class', 'radio');
                $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'radio-checked');
                $check.attr('checked', true);
            }).on('keydown', function (e) {
                if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 32) {
                    $(this).trigger('click');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this working example:

```js
function testMe() { 
  if ($("input:radio[name='travel_mode']").is(":checked")) {
    alert($("input:radio[name='travel_mode']:checked").attr("value"));
    // or
    alert($("input:radio[name='travel_mode']:checked").val());
  } else { 
    alert("You must make a choice!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skin_1" title="Walk">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_walking" value="WALKING" /><br>
    Walk
</div>

<div id="skin_2" title="Drive">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_driving" value="DRIVING" /><br>
    Drive
</div>

<div id="skin_3" title="Bike">
    <input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_bicycle" value="BICYCLING" /><br>
    Bike
</div>

<div id="skin_4" title="Transit">
<input type="radio" name="travel_mode" id="mode_transit" value="TRANSIT" /><br>
 Transit
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" onClick="testMe();">What mode is selected?</a>
</div>
```